# Number of solutions of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find the number of principal solutions of the equation $$\sec^2x+\sin^2x=2\sin x$$ I have no idea how to proceed. Converting in sine gives biquadratic...

Comment: To get an idea of what is happening, graph the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the equation. You will see that there are no real values of x where the two graphs meet.

Answer (score 1):

There appears more algebra than trigonometry here.

$ s = \sin (x), $ please check the work..

$ 1 + s^2/c^2 + s^2 = 2 s \rightarrow s^4 - 2 s^3 -s^2 + 2 s -1 = 0 $..

two complex, two real roots etc.

EDIT1:

Mathematica output:

$\text{NSolve}[ s{}^{\wedge}4- 2 s{}^{\wedge}3 -s{}^{\wedge}2 + 2 s -1==0,s]$

$\{\{s\to -1.13224\},\{s\to 0.5@ -0.405233 i\},\{s\to 0.5@ +0.405233 i\},\{s\to 2.13224\}\} $

*All* $x$ are complex.The difference of real roots is 3, don't know why so..

Comment: How did you get the roots? I want the values of real roots.